# Oracle SQL*Plus multiline comment when slash is defined as command delimiter?

Tags: sql, oracle, maven, sqlplus

Is there a way to have multiline comments with SQL*Plus when the SQL command delimiter is set to a slash (`/`)?

The following will throw an error:

```
/* ----------------------------------
 * Random comment
---------------------------------- */
```

The error message reads

```
/* ----------------------------------
 * Random comment
---------------------------------- *
[ERROR] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Clearly, the closing comment is interpreted as a statement terminator.

We use this when defining a package:

```
create package Foo AS
  /* ----------------------------------
   * Bar returns baz
  ---------------------------------- */
  PROCEDURE Bar(baz OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN baz FOR
    SELECT abc
      FROM ttt;
  END bar;
END Foo;
/
```

NB: we actually use the [maven-sql-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/execute-mojo.html) to run this, but I'm told it follows SQL*Plus syntax?

Our POM settings are as follows:

```
<autocommit>true</autocommit>
<delimiter>/</delimiter>
<delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>
<orderFile>ascending</orderFile>
<onError>continue</onError>
<keepFormat>true</keepFormat>
```

Comment: I think the problem might have stemmed from someone setting the POM from `<delimiterType>row</delimiterType>` to `normal`, actually...?

Comment: SQL\*Plus doesn't complain about that with sqlterminator set to /. I'd guess Maven is parsing the statements out of the file based on the terminator to execute them individually via JDBC, and it's that parsing which is getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

SQL PLus allows for comments, see the below test.
But you are trying to create a procedure definition in the package itself rather that in the package body, and this can be a reason of the error.
The package can contain only a declaration of the procedure.
The procedure definition must be in the package body.

```
SQL> create package Foo AS
  2    /* ----------------------------------
  3     * Bar returns baz
  4    ---------------------------------- */
  5    PROCEDURE Bar(baz OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
  6  end;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> create package body Foo As
  2    /* ----------------------------------
  3     * Bar returns baz
  4    ---------------------------------- */
  5    PROCEDURE Bar(baz OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  6    IS
  7    BEGIN
  8      OPEN baz FOR
  9      SELECT abc
 10        FROM ttt;
 11    END bar;
 12  END Foo;
 13  /

Package body created.
```